# Code works fine in eclipse but crashes when exported

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

So, I've made a game using Libgdx in eclipse for android/desktop. The strange thing is that when I export it to a desktop app, it doesn't exports my assets into the JAR(I should put them manually for it to work properly). When I try running my app on android (AVD's and my phone) it uploads the app, but then stops(Unfortunately *the game* stopped).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUAoZ.jpg You can see my project structure here.

**I've double checked if the "Extract required libraries...." is enabled and if the assets folder is set as a working directory. I also got the latest version of Gradle installed and tested in cmd.**

The weird things is that if I save and send my project to a friend of mine, he can export it to desktop and it exports all of the assets and he also can run it on his tablet and AVD - so i thing the problem is not from the code, but from the eclipse/gradle settings.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Essentially *any* "my app crashes on Android" question is incomplete if it does not include the logcat output showing the crash.  The rare exceptions might be when you don't have access to the device where it occurs, but you do.

Comment: Here, I exported the logCat log file.
http://textuploader.com/d5mpr
Sorry for the text file, but it was quite long for a screenshot.

Comment: You shouldn't be using screenshots, but rather putting things in the body of your question.  This seems key: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kiril.main.game.AndroidLauncher"` so likely either part of the code didn't make it into your app or else your manifest mismatches what did.  Look at existing questions, it is unlikely that your difficulty is unique.